# How to browse the internet on C# windows forms panel?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating simple browser just navigate the "google".

How can I do it in my point?

```
Viewer = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();

private void Browser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                WebBrowser web1 = new WebBrowser();

                web1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");


                Viewer = web1 // It gets error




            }
```

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp-and-windows-forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag out the WebBrowser control like you would with any other control..

Then access it by its name (default would be WebBrowser1 i think so modify your code to be `WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");`.)

Answer (score 1):

Reason for error is you are trying convert "Web Browser" control to "Panel" control type.

Change :

```
     Viewer = web1;
```

To:

```
     Viewer.Controls.Add(web1); // add as child control
     web1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // fill style in viewer
```

Make sure your viewer is docked in Parent control as needed.
Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Hey it works thanks.
But it shows just 4x4 windows how do that's dock get filled?

Comment: Change the property `web1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; Viewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`, if you placed it with the designer you can just change this property from the properties grid and see the results directly.

Comment: Hey Peter I created it, works but it get that error: Script error "error has occured in the script on this page"

Comment: @user2801618 im sorry but i have no idea why you get "error has occurred in the script on this page", but you could try to go to some page that does not contain any scripts and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter

I resolved that problem with " webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true; "

Answer (score 0):

try 
web1.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");